# How to use Gulp with Hakyll

Tags: haskell, gulp, hakyll

I'm new to [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) and thought I would start by making a blog with [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/).  I'm also using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for pre-processing my js and scss.

How do I go about generating my js and css files when I build my Hakyll site?

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to finding your solution would be [using clay with hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/using-clay-with-hakyll.html) in the section of integrating clay we have

```
match "css/*.hs" $ do
    route   $ setExtension "css"
    compile $ getResourceString >>= withItemBody (unixFilter "runghc" [])

-- cabal sandbox users can use (unixFilter "cabal" ["exec", "runghc"])
-- given that you've added cabal to your PATH
```

I think you can replace the `"runghc" []` part with the according `"gulp" ["buildcss"]` and add another section `match "js/*.js`

```
match "css/*.scss" $ do
        route   $ setExtension "css"
        compile $ getResourceString >>= withItemBody (unixFilter "gulp" ["buildcss"])

match "js/*.js" $ do
            route   $ setExtension "js"
            compile $ getResourceString >>= withItemBody (unixFilter "gulp" ["buildjs"])
```

Note: this code is untested for I don't use gulp in my setup.